# Typescript Cloud Functions debugging in VS Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions, vscode-debugger

From my terminal I run `firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore --inspect-functions`.

I currently have this `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Typescript Functions",
            "port": 9229,
            "restart": true,
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/typescript-functions/lib/*.js.map"]
        }
    ]
}
```

My intention is to debug a server side endpoint, calling it through POSTMAN. I've been digging different documentation and guides, but I haven't had the ability to exactly find demos or guides regarding the necessary **Typescript** mapping.

The launch.json is inside the `.vscode` folder, at the root level. Then I have my `typescript-functions`folder, where inside of it I have a `src`folder with all the **Typescript** code.

Then, there is a `lib`folder where all the transpiled code exists in *javascript*, with their respective source maps.

[image]

What am I missing?

I've been reading different questions:

[Functions debugging in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920014/functions-debugging-in-vs-code)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging#_mapping-the-output-location

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps

[VS Code Unbound breakpoints: We couldn't find a corresponding source location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75339578/vs-code-unbound-breakpoints-we-couldnt-find-a-corresponding-source-location)

But unfortunately, haven't had the ability to find out the solution yet. I have verified, that if my code was written in JS, the debugger works as expected and stops the execution correctly, so my conclusion is that i'm basically missing the part where i'm linking the typescript source mapping, and where does the debugger need to look at.

Thanks :)

Comment: You should modify the `"outFiles"` path accordingly. `"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/typescript-functions/lib/**/*.js"]`. Additionally, ensure that you have the `"sourceMap"` option enabled in your TypeScript configuration (`tsconfig.json`).

Comment: Hi @Chanpols, I did try that, but still can't manage to get it to work? What else could I be missing? What other information would be useful for you to help me find out the issue? Thanks :)